# Search in windows control panel lose focus after typing one character

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-search, control-panel

When I open windows' control panel, click the search bar and start typing, it always lose focus after typing in one character. If I click it again to regain focus, the problem wouldn't happen again. I'm wondering if this is a feature or a bug? As far as I can tell it happens in windows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too found the same problem with a new W7 laptop, but have a solution.

The answer it to make sure you have your **Control Panel** window set to 
**VIEW BY: CATEGORY**

As much as you may hate this setting, it's worth the pain to avoid the Windows bug. In fact, with this setting not only does the *'focus lost after first keystroke'* problem go away, but you will also find **the search box is given initial focus** when you first open the control panel window. Very important for keyboard addicts!

Comment: THanks this works! I do hate view by category, but this approach solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you type the first character in the **control panel's search bar** then it shows the result of the programs that started with that character and move the focus to that list. You can call it **feature** but if you don't get the name in that list and you have to type the full name in search bar to get the specific program.

Comment: Thanks avirk! It's the type of feature I don't really get though :)