# Auto focus on control panel's search box

Tags: windows, automation, windows-search, control-panel, focus

I am not sure if this applies to Windows in general or just Windows 7.

On my old Windows 7 computer, whenever I would open the Control Panel the search box would be in focus.  On my new Windows 7 computer, this is not the case; to make it worse, even when I type something into the search box and press backspace to clear the search box, then the search box loses focus; and [also after typing one letter into the search box, it loses focus](https://superuser.com/questions/535967/search-in-windows-control-panel-lose-focus-after-typing-one-character).

This is highly annoying, but I cannot remember how I got the search box to be in auto focus on my old computer, hence I cannot do it for this computer, does anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too found the same problem with a new W7 laptop.

The answer it to make sure you have your **Control Panel** window set to 
**VIEW BY: CATEGORY**

As much as you may hate this setting, it's worth the pain to avoid these Windows bugs; it fixes both the *'focus lost after first keystroke'* AND the *'search box initial focus'*. Very important for keyboard addicts!

Comment: I do not mind view by category because the search is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

It should auto-focus and stay there like your old computer did, there's no way to change this behaviour via a simple setting.

So it sounds to me like you have something wrong with your new computer.

Try it in Safe Mode, if it works as expected, it's a piece of 3rd party software that's running and interfering.  If that's the case then you can use MSConfig to disable things, and then re-enable them one at a time until you identify the culprit.